# Regex match last occurrence of a string from multiple lines

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match the last occurrences of a string from a log file.

```
[03/03/2019 09:16:36] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING
[03/03/2019 09:16:36] Retrieving file(s) of type DATAWAREHOUSE for 123456
[03/03/2019 09:16:36] collecting warehouse version 7.3.1 files for 123456...
[03/03/2019 09:16:37] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING
[03/03/2019 09:16:37] Retrieving file(s) of type DATAWAREHOUSE for 123456
[03/03/2019 09:16:37] collecting warehouse version 7.3.1 files for 123456...
[03/03/2019 09:16:38] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING
[03/03/2019 09:16:39] Retrieving file(s) of type DATAWAREHOUSE for 123456
[03/03/2019 09:16:40] collecting warehouse version 7.3.1 files for 123456...
```

Above is the sample log file from which there are three occurrences of the below string,

```
Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING
```

I need to match the last occurrence to get the respective timestamp "***[03/03/2019 09:16:38]***".
But when all these are in a single line using greedy approach (.*) it works fine. But when they are present in multiple lines it isn't working. I haven't tried multiline (m) as I'm not sure how to use it. Can someone please help me construct the regex query to retrive this last occurrence timestamp?
Example: https://regex101.com/r/fnwPsB/1

Comment: Perhaps, like `(?s:.*\n)?\K\[\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING`? See https://regex101.com/r/fnwPsB/2

Comment: See this: https://regex101.com/r/fnwPsB/3

Comment: Both works great! thank you so much.
@anubhava 's is exactly what I need. Thanks both of you!

Comment: FYI: To get a substring out of a whole match, you need to use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), so the `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` pattern should be enclosed with capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is not dependent on PCRE feature using negative lookahead:

```
(?s)\[(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING(?!.* Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnwPsB/4)

Date-time is available in 1st capture group.

Here `(?!.* Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING)` is negative lookahead that ensures we match very last occurrence of given pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?s:.*\n)?\K\[(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnwPsB/5)

**Details**

- `(?s:.*\n)?` - an inline modifier group that matches any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last LF char that is followed with the last occurrence of the subsequent patterns.
- `\K`  - match reset operator removing all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `\[(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING` - the specific line pattern to get with the datetime captured in Group 1.

Alternatively, use

```
(?s)(\[\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING)(?!.*(?1))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9AT5y8/2).

**Details**

- `(?s)` -  DOTALL modifier making `.` match any char
- `(\[(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] Moving message 123456789 from NEW to PENDING)` - the necessary pattern to match captured into Group 1 and the datetime in Group 2
- `(?!.*(?1))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is the same pattern as defined in Group 1 after any  0+ chars to the right of the current position.

Comment: @tuxian Just noticed you need the date captured separately, edited